# Why does a Webwork method in my plugin fall back into JIRA's ActionSupport class?

Tags: java, excel, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am having troubles with an Excel File uploaded into a Webwork `Action` class in my JIRA plugin.
I am using apache.poi to manipulate the Excel file as follows:

```
public class ExcelWebworkAction extends JiraWebActionSupport
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7589391189615316463L;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExcelWebworkAction.class);

    @Override
    public String doExecute() throws Exception {
        MultiPartRequestWrapper wrapper = (MultiPartRequestWrapper)ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        File file = wrapper.getFile("fileField");
        FileInputStream filestrem = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;

        try {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(filestrem);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            }
        }

        filestrem.close();

        return super.doExecute(); //returns SUCCESS
    }

}
```

When the code gets to the line:

```
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(filestrem);
```

I am kicked out of the class to a class called `ActionSupport` from JIRA, but with no errors or stacktraces to guide me.

Am I missing something? It there something wrong? :(

Thanks in advance for any insights on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying library is probably throwing some sort of unchecked exception. To debug, try changing:

```
catch (IOException e)
```

to:

```
catch (Throwable e)
```

and then set a breakpoint on the `e.printStackTrace()` line.

(Or wrap the whole method in the try/catch block if you're not 100% sure of exactly where it's crashing.)

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for taking the time to look into this.
Yeah, that was it, now I got an error to look into! :)
Some class is not being loaded right. 

Thanks a bunch! :)